# ng-click not firing within ngdialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a very basic ng-click inside of an NgDialog that will not fire when being clicked on and was wondering anyone had any ideas on what the issue could be.

`this.clickLocation = function () {
  ngDialog.open({
    plain: true,
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      console.log('hit');
    }],
    template: '<div class="ngdialog-content">' +
      '<a ng-click="closeThisDialog()" class="button">Remove</a>' +
      '</div>'
  });
}`

Comment: That is not the right approach, add custom dirctive in template, also add the  closeThisDialog() function or it will downvoted.

Comment: Itsik Mauyhas, he is using ngDialog, if you check https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog you'll see that `closeThisDialog()` is a function from the library and that gets injected into the scope.

Comment: closeThisDialog() is a built-in function in ngDialog that should close the dialog on fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't really able to reproduce your error, but I created the following jsfiddle with everything working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/bqbrLczc/5/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {
    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ 
            plain: true,
            controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                        console.log('hit');
            }],
            template: '<div class="test">'+ 
            '<a ng-click="closeThisDialog()" class="button">Remove</a>' + 
            '</div>' 
        });
    };
}
```

Please check if theres anything missing from your code or if you're using a old and possibly bugged version.

Comment: Thanks to your post I noticed the big difference between yours and mine were that you had an ng-controller and I did not... after some searching around I found out that there was a bug with ngdialog and angular version 1.2 and updating ngdialog resolved the issue... thank you :)